# summarize original data based on expand grid categories

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to summarize a table using dplyr. 
Here is how I would like to proceed:

- I have a data.frame like this:

```
 year    region week  site           species    gps_clutch
2017    sud   18     6                  au        337
2017    sud   20     10                 au        352
2017    sud   22     10                 au        352
2017    sud   24     10                 au        352
2017    sud   18     6                  aio       337
2017    sud   20     6                  aio       352
2017    sud   22     6                  au        352
2018    sud   20     6                  au        337
2018    sud   20     10                 au        352
2018    sud   22     10                 au        352
2018    sud   22     10                 aio       352
2018    sud   22     6                  au        352
2017    nor   19     5                  au        337
2017    nor   21     2                  au        352
2017    nor   23     5                  au        352
2017    nor   25     2                  au        352
2017    nor   19     5                  aio       337
2017    nor   25     5                  aio       352
2017    nor   19     5                  au        337
2018    nor   21     2                  aio       352
2018    nor   23     5                  aio        352
2018    nor   25     2                  au        352
2018    nor   23     5                  aio       337
2018    nor   23     5                  au       352
```

- I would like to count the number of "gps_clutch" for each year, region, site, week and expand this all the possible weeks recorded for each region. I explain: in the region "sud" I sampled week 18, 20, 22, 24 and in the region "nor" week 19, 21, 23, 25. I would like to convert implicit missing values by "0" but only for the weeks (nested in regions) that have been sampled.  I do not want to expand in a way that I would get a row for week 19 in region "sud" because this region was not sampled that specific week.

this code works well to expand the grid as I would like:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  expand(year,site, species,week)
```

the following code works too, to get the count values but does not expand the grid as I wish (I only get the list of weeks for which I did observe something for each year, not the total number of weeks sampled across both years). Which mean that if in "sud" "2017" I only have records for weeks 20 and 22, the grid will not get expanded to week 18 and 24 :

```
field_subsetnord %>%
  group_by(year,region,site,species,week) %>%
  summarise(count_clutch=length(gps_clutch)) %>% 
  complete(week,nesting(year,sites,species), fill = list(count_clutch = 0))
```

this is the table I would like to get at the end:

```
 year    region week  site           species    count
2017     sud    18     6             au         1
2017     sud    20     6             au         0
2017     sud    22     6             au         1
2017     sud    24     6             au         0

2017     sud    18     6             aio        1
2017     sud    20     6             aio        1
2017     sud    22     6             aio        0
2017     sud    24     6             aio        0

2017     sud    18     10            au         0
2017     sud    20     10            au         1
2017     sud    22     10            au         1
2017     sud    24     10            au         1

2017     sud    18     10            aio        0
2017     sud    20     10            aio        0
2017     sud    22     10            aio        0
2017     sud    24     10            aio        0

2018     sud    18     6             au        0
2018     sud    20     6             au        1
2018     sud    22     6             au        1
2018     sud    24     6             au        0

2018     sud    18     6             aio       0
2018     sud    20     6             aio       0
2018     sud    22     6             aio       0 
2018     sud    24     6             aio       0

2018     sud    18     10            au        0
2018     sud    20     10            au        1
2018     sud    22     10            au        1
2018     sud    24     10            au        0

2018     sud    18     10            aio       0
2018     sud    20     10            aio       0
2018     sud    22     10            aio       1
2018     sud    24     10            aio       0

and so on for 2018...
```

any suggestions to mix these two codes would be appreciated :)

Comment: You can specify `week = 18:24` to specify the values which should be expanded. From the explanation you are given I'm not completly sure whether tha's what you are intending. Please make the examples more reproducible, by providing the data in a reproducible format and including all samples (e.g. 18 for sud is not in the data you're showing)

Comment: I just edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close with your two approaches.  Essentially they just need to be combined to get what you're after. :)

Group by region and then `complete()` the dataset first, then regroup by all variables and `summarise()`.  Since the `gps_clutch` will now have missing values in it, you can sum up the non-missing values (via `!is.na`) in the `summarise()` statement to count the clutches.

```
dat %>%
    group_by(region) %>%
    complete(year, site, species, week) %>% 
    group_by(year, region, site, species, week) %>%
    summarise(count_clutch = sum( !is.na(gps_clutch) ) )

# A tibble: 64 x 6
# Groups:   year, region, site, species [16]
    year region  site species  week count_clutch
   <int> <fct>  <int> <fct>   <int>        <int>
 1  2017 nor        2 aio        19            0
 2  2017 nor        2 aio        21            0
 3  2017 nor        2 aio        23            0
 4  2017 nor        2 aio        25            0
 5  2017 nor        2 au         19            0
 6  2017 nor        2 au         21            1
 7  2017 nor        2 au         23            0
 8  2017 nor        2 au         25            1
 9  2017 nor        5 aio        19            1
10  2017 nor        5 aio        21            0
# ... with 54 more rows
```

Comment: indeed! thanks for your help. There is something I cannot really understand though is that my script only work if my variables are passed "as.character". If they are factors it does not work any longer. Is it the way it should be?

Comment: @user3016665 Factors can definitely cause difficulties in some cases.  For example, sometimes they'll get converted to show their index (integer) instead of the character value.  The example I show above is using factors for "region" and "species", though, and it seems to have worked OK (looks like I'm using the dev versions of both dplyr and tidyr).

Comment: a last question, if I would like to get both the count_clutch (as in the example) per year>region>site>sites>week and another column which would count by group but stopping at the site level (it would correspond to the sum over the week variable). How would I proceed to include that in the same code. Should I add another "group_by" to make this different count?

Comment: @user3016665 I'm not totally sure I understand, but `summarise()` always drops the "last" grouping variable.  So at the end of the pipe in my answer things are grouped by everything except week (since the data are on the week level now).  If you wanted to then add a variable to represent the total number of weeks with clutches, you could do something like `%>% mutate(nweek = sum( count_clutch != 0) )`.  To summarize over weeks instead of adding a summary column, use `summarise()`.